# Can the Stack Exchange league tables show percentile as well as rank?

Tags: feature-request, reputation-leagues

Currently profiles show "top X% this [week/month/quarter/etc]" and clicking shows the user reputation league tables.

But there is no visibility of what percent the rank equates to in those tables, they only show:

`rank` `change` `total` `period rank`

Adding percent, since it seems to already be calculated, should be easy.

Comment: Do want! I'm a little obsessive about comparing monthly, quarterly, and yearly percentages to see if I might have just a slightly less favorable percentile over a substantially larger period of time, but finding the raw numbers and calculating the results in PowerShell is tedious.

Answer (score 3):

Have a [userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/6485/show-each-users-percentile-in-rep-leagues) to calculate this client-side and show it in (at present) the hover titles over each user's rank:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Show Rep League Percentile
// @namespace   com.tuggy.nathan
// @description Displays percentile for the current time period when hovering over a user's rank
// @include     *://stackexchange.com/leagues/*
// @version     1.0.00
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

const percentPerUnit = 100;

var allDeltaUsersInPeriodCount = new Number(document.querySelector(".sidebar-stats tr:last-child .count").textContent);
var ranks = document.querySelectorAll(".statsWrapper > :first-child .number");
for (let rank of ranks) {
  let n = new Number(rank.textContent.substring(1));
  let pct = n / allDeltaUsersInPeriodCount, rounding = pct < 0.01 ? 1000 : 100;
  let rpct = (Math.round(pct * percentPerUnit * rounding) / rounding) + "%";
  rank.parentNode.title = rpct;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I support the concept of rewarding individuals, for desired behaviour, in a way that works for them. Therefore, I would like to see the OP rewarded for their contribution.

In principle, however, I would prefer that internal-community-rank enhancements receive a lower priority than, for example, feature-requests that might enhance the value of SE to the wider community.

Would the addition of this feature-request increase the positive contributions of the OP and a significant number of others like them? If so, then I support it.

Comment: Just because something's less important doesn't mean that it should be disregarded completely. As the question mentioned, the value is already being calculated, and seems missing on the leaderboard pages.